# select large table in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, out-of-memory

I would like to know how to get very large number of rows in the controller, and dispay it to the view. my current code looks likes below.

**this is the controller.**

```
$users = \App\Models\User::select ('id','first_name','last_name','created_at')
            ->where('friend_id', '=', 0)
            ->orderBy('created_at')->get();

return view('layouts.users.friends', compact('users'));
```

**this is the view.**

```
@if (!empty($users))
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <tr>
                            <?php $count++ ?>
                            <td>
                                {!! $user->id !!}
                            </td>
                            <td>{!! $user->first_name .'   ' .$user->last_name !!}</td>
                            <td> {!! $user->created_at->format("d-m-y") !!} </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
```

Now i have 40,000 rows in the table, and when try to get the view error code 500, outof memory. I have to get all the rows. Please advice me what should be done. here. I have heard about laravel 5 chunk. but dont know who to display it on the view. Please help.

Comment: Do you try paginate? for example get only 10  or 100 row per page ?

Comment: I cant do pagination since i have to create excel file after displaying the data. in the view. and the excel plugin does not support pagination

Comment: Have you checked `memory_limit` in `php.ini ` ?

Comment: Yes it is fine, i think i have to use pagination since, no one want to see a excel file with 40,000 rows. i hope i will find the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to show data then, you can use `pagination`. You can see official documentation for pagination [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results).

If you need other complex calculation and operations you need some loop optimization methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that are possible here, The one I would personally attempt to do as a hack is to chunk the result and in the process assemble the view portion I need then pass it to the main view:

So you can have something like this:

```
$the_view = "";
\App\Models\User::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'created_at')
        ->where('friend_id', '=', 0)
        ->orderBy('created_at')->chunk(4000, function ($user_chunk) use (&$the_view) {
            foreach ($user_chunk as $user) {
                $the_view .= "<td >" . $user->id . "</td >" .
                    "<td >" . $user->first_name . " " . $user->last_name . "</td >" .
                    "<td > " . $user->created_at->format('d-m-y') .
                    " </td ></tr >";
            }
});
return view('layouts.users.friends', compact('the_view'));
```

Then in your view, simply escape it as html:

```
{ !! $the_view !! }
```

I will not say this is proven to work but I think it should.

Other **Not recommended way** is to play around with your memory limit example:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

> PS: Like I said its not recommended. Try the chunk and see it gives an Idea of what you can do.